# Zooming and panning svg images using raphael.js or some other js library

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am in need of a small script that will display an SVG (vector image) within a frame that has 2 functions;

1. The image can be panned (moved around to look at different parts of
   the svg image with the cursor) simmilar to google maps.
2. The SVG image can be zoomed in and out on also simmilar to google
   maps except there will be no need to load new imagery as the image
   is a vector.

For a simmilar script i have seen that works with normal image formats see http://jibbering.com/routeplanner/

Comment: Also this functionality should work on all the broswers including ie(not ie 6) without the need to download and install a svg viewer plugin.

Comment: No version of IE supports SVG (without a plugin), so this "small script" will at the very least need to convert SVG to VML.  That's a pretty big job right there: the SVG spec is 719 pages long!

Comment: @Chandan You've had some useful answers - suggest you accept one of them

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If someone is still interested: I just found this implementation of Pan and Zoom for Raphael. Still a very young project, but interesting enough I think:

https://github.com/escobar5/raphael-pan-zoom

Online demo here:
http://htmlpreview.github.com/?https://raw.github.com/escobar5/raphael-pan-zoom/master/examples/complete-map/index.html

Comment: is this plugin have a documentation or a quick start page?

Comment: I'm afraid no. There are 2 examples in the examples folder. For more I think you have to contact the author

Answer (score 20):

Raphael is good, but not good enough.

Check out this page: http://code.google.com/p/svgpan/. It does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Does this library have any documentation? It would be great if there were some way to make it zoom in when a specific function was called on a web page.

Answer (score 12):

I've derived Andrea's SVGPan into a (hopefully) more friendly [Raphäel plugin](https://github.com/andrewseddon/raphael-zpd) :)

Comment: Hey, do you have the plugin up anywhere? The github page is no longer available.

Comment: @VicSzpilman https://github.com/andrewseddon/raphael-zpd ?

Answer (score 4):

First you need to learn how to install a function that extends Raphael to support zooming...
http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.html?q=addownmethodstocanvas

Next you want to implement Wout's zooming plugin...
http://github.com/wout/raphael-zoom

Comment: Both links are now dead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the scripts from IE9 test page http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/42OrganizationChart/Default.xhtml Requires a little tweaking with ids but worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the [svg-pan-zoom](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom) which is derived from SVGPan, but allows zoomin/panning of an arbitrary `svg` element within your HTML, and can add controls.

SVGPan works great if your complete page is just a loaded SVG (like the tiger example), but not if your svg is somewhere deeper in the html.