# Is there a library or tool for svg or raphael that allows to pan over and zoom into drawings?

Tags: dictionary, svg, zooming, raphael, vector-graphics

Does somebody know if there is a library (or something like a library) that allows me to create text annoted vector graphics (preferably on the basis of svg or raphael) with the feature to pan over these graphics and zoom into them and, when I zoom into, shows more and more details, or, when zooming out, shows less details so that the image is not cluttered with details that are irrelevant for a particular zoom level.

I am aware I could do the panning and zooming with setting a corresponding viewport, but this would still show details that I don't want to see on a zoomed-out level.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Possible repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339374/zooming-and-panning-svg-images-using-raphael-js-or-some-other-js-library

Answer (score 1):

SVGPan is a small script for this pourpose:

http://code.google.com/p/svgpan/

demo page:

http://www.cyberz.org/projects/SVGPan/tiger.svg

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution provided here using Raphael

http://dashasalo.com/2011/04/13/svg-image-zooming-and-panning-with-raphaeljs/

Comment: As far as I can see this example lacks the feature that it shows more details as I zoom in, it is still the same picture but larger.