# How to reduce the image size of an SVG image?

Tags: html, svg, raphael

I have a drawn an image using Raphael framework. It is an SVG image. I want to resize it.

How is it possible?

Help me please

Thanks,

Comment: Reduce how - how large and complex is it? What does it contain?

Comment: reduce to small sized image..It contains an image

Comment: Do you mean zoom/resolution, or file size?

Comment: reduce resolution. not file size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [setViewBox](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setViewBox) to set the coordinate system, then set the canvas size with [setSize](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setSize).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that zooming an SVG image is not supported directly in Raphael. There are ways to extend that, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339374/zooming-and-panning-svg-images-using-raphael-js-or-some-other-js-library) question's answers show. One of the guys shares a link to a plugin that does that.